# Complex Solutions using Lambert W Function, How does it work?

Tags: complex-numbers, lambert-w

According to this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3713282/664855), Lambert W function $"W_k(f(x))"$ has only 2 branches $(k=0,\,k=-1)$. But, there's an equation that has $4$ solutions ($2$ real solutions and $2$ complex solutions which is a pair of complex conjugates).

The equation is:
$$\frac{x^3}{24} - \ln{x} =0$$
The solutions:

1. $e^{-\frac 13 W_{-1} \left(-\frac 18\right)}$ (Real solution)
2. $e^{-\frac 13 W_{0} \left(-\frac 18\right)}$ (Real solution)
3. $e^{-\frac 13 W_{1} \left(-\frac 18\right)}$ (Complex solution)
4. $e^{-\frac 13 W_{2} \left(-\frac 18\right)}$ (Complex solution)

And what i want to ask here is how to find those complex solutions? Yeah, algebraically i can solve that equation by myself. But, then how to determine $k=({-1,0,1,2})$? for finding the entire solutions? This question is related to the given link, but they weren't discussing about how to obtain complex solutions using this special function and how to determine the value of $k$.

I mean, consider if i have an equation that has $7$ solutions (just for a random example), and actually those solutions are obtained by determining all possibilities of the value of $k$. Again, how do we know that? Cz since we never know how to find $k$ we can't find the whole solutions.

Hope you can help me to understand. Thanks!

Comment: "... has only 2 branches $(k=0,k=-1)$...". That should be: "has only 2 REAL branches $(k=0,k=-1)$...". ANY $k$ branch of the $W_k$ expression you find would be a solution.

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis yes forgive me, it should be 2 real branches, cz i just copied from the given link. Anyway, you said "any" $k$ would be a solution, but then i tried to test for $k=2$ on my equation above and didn't give the true statement. It only has 4 solutions. 2 real numbers and 2 complex numbers. I just don't have an idea how to find $k$ such that i get those complex solution.

Comment: That's because your equation is an equation in the reals (contains the real $\log$). If your equation was extended in the complexes, it would contain $\log(z)$ and that's a multivalued function, so you'd need to consider your solutions vis-a-vis the complex $\log_k$. For example: $z=\exp(-1/3 W_2(-1/8))$ ($k=2$ for $W$), doesn't satisfy the real equation, but does satisfy the complex equation: $z^3/24-\log_{-1}(z)=0$ ($k=-1$ for $\log$). Look up on the definition of the complex $\log$. The real equation is satisfied with the $W_k$ solutions for $k=\{-1,-2,0,1\}$ only.

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis ok thanks. But still not answering my question on "how to determine the value of $k$ on the real equation"

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28exp%28-1%2F3+productlog%282%2C-1%2F8%29%29%29%5E3+%3D+24log%28-1%2Cexp%28-1%2F3+productlog%282%2C-1%2F8%29%29%29 tried to verify but still got false. Why?

Comment: There's no offhand way to determine all the $k$ for which $W_k$ satisfies the real equation.You just have to try all $k$ by hand. I got -1,-2,0 and 1 by numerical check. Other than that, sorry, I don't know what notation Wolfram uses for the complex $\log$, so I can't tell why it doesn't verify the $W_2$ solution. Maybe try to read up on the documentation of Wolfram's input format for how $\log_k$ is specified. The definition I am using in Maple is: $\log_k(z)=Log(z)+2k\pi i$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $Log(z)$ is the principal branch of $\log$. Using this, Maple verifies it.

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis Thank you, i'l try.